# How many grids in CUDA

Tags: cuda, parallel-processing, gpu, nvidia

How many CUDA grids are possible in a GPU?

Can two grids exist together in a GPU? Or does one GPU device have only one grid?

```
Kernel1<<gridDim, blockDim>>(dst1, param1);
Kernel1<<gridDim, blockDim>>(dst2, param2);
```

Do two kernels  above run concurrently or sequentially?

Answer (score 9):

If the two kernels are issued as indicated above, they will be serialized (they will run sequentially).  This is because without any other code (i.e. to switch streams) the two kernels will be issued to the same cuda stream.  All cuda calls issued to the same stream are executed sequentially, even if you think you should see otherwise because you're using cudaMemcpyAsync or something like that.

It's certainly possible to have multiple kernels running asynchronously with respect to each other (so possibly concurrently) but it's necessary to use the cuda streams API to accomplish this.

You may want to look at Section 3.2.5 "Asynchronous Concurrent Execution" in the [CUDA C Programmers Guide](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DevZone/docs/html/C/doc/CUDA_C_Programming_Guide.pdf) to learn more about streams and concurrent kernel execution.   In addition, there are a number of samples in the nvidia [CUDA SDK](http://developer.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-cc-sdk-code-samples) such as [simple streams](http://developer.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-cc-sdk-code-samples#simpleStreams) which will illustrate the concepts.  The [concurrent kernels](http://developer.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-cc-sdk-code-samples#concurrentKernels) sample shows how to run multiple kernels concurrently (using streams).  Note that running kernels concurrently requires compute capability 2.0 or "higher" hardware.

Also, to answer your first question, from [section 3.2.5.2](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#concurrent-kernel-execution) of the CUDA C Programming guide, "The maximum number of kernel launches that a device can execute concurrently varies by device but may be as high as 128 for some devices"

For reference, a "grid" is the entire thread array associated with a single kernel launch.

Comment: You should also answer the initial question: "how many [concurrent] grids are possible on a GPU" -- 1 for CC < 2.0, 16 for 2.0 <= CC <= 3.0, and 32 for CC = 3.5.

Comment: @harrism It maybe quite unrelated, but What does Hyper-Q offers in this scenario?

Comment: Hyper-Q offers the possibility of more efficient GPU usage when the kernels are being launched by independent processes on the CPU.  The cuda stream API would normally be used to manage overlapping kernels launched from a single process.

Comment: @RobertCrovella "The maximum number of kernel launches that a device can execute concurrently is sixteen" is it related to the device? i.e it differs from one GPU to another?

Comment: Yes, and it is covered in the programming guide section 3.2.5.2, see [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#concurrent-kernel-execution)

Answer (score 4):

To elaborate on Robert's answer, here's an example of how you could use streams to make your two instances of `Kernel1` run concurrently:

```
cudaStream_t stream1; cudaStreamCreate(&stream1);
cudaStream_t stream2; cudaStreamCreate(&stream2);

Kernel1<<gridDim, blockDim, 0, stream1>>(dst1, param1);
Kernel1<<gridDim, blockDim, 0, stream2>>(dst2, param2);
```

A few more notes about concurrent execution with streams:

- If we launch a kernel without specifying a stream `Kernel1<<<g, b>>>()`, and then launch a kernel with a specific stream `Kernel2<<<g, b, 0, stream>>>()`, then `Kernel2` will wait for `Kernel1` to finish.
- When a kernel is launched without a stream (`Kernel1<<<g, b>>>()`), Nvidia calls this "using the NULL stream."
- If you use `cudaEvents`, your work can sometimes get serialized even if you distribute the kernels over several streams.